# Android NDK doesn't link static library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

Some mystery is going on with my project :)

I have a shared library that uses libjpeg which is static library. It all worked fine but now when I need to add a few changes to the project it just stopped including libjpeg in my shared module.

So before when it worked, my shared module (.so file) was around 90Kb and now it 4Kb and application can't run saying that it can't find libjpeg.so

And folders structure is following:
/platform/libjpeg - include files for libjpeg
/platform/libraries - contain libjpeg.a and a few other libraries

---

UPDATE: After playing around with the projects I figured out that the problem appeared after I wanted to add android:installLocation into manifest. Following Google's recommendations for backward compatibility (http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) I changed project's API level to 8 (so it parses manifest without errors) and left minSdkVersion="7" (so it runs on previous version). However, this particular change in the project affects the NDK build. Probably, libjpeg is included in android-8 and it doesn't want to build it in as a static library?

Anyway, the question is: Is it possible in eclipse to ignore error about installLocation in manifest using API level 7 or is it possible to force ndk-build to use API level 7 while keeping level 8 in the project settings?

Answer (score 0):

In NDK you can find document docs/ANDROID-MK.html. In this document you will find option TARGET_PLATFORM. This should help.

Comment: Just tried this, but doesn't work. Seems that Eclipse's setting has higher priority.